# Join two lists with unique values

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list of two different types:

- `List<LoginTable> loginList = AllLoginTableUser();`
- `List<UserInformation> users = GetAllUserInformation();`

Their columns:

- LoginTable contains LoginId, Password, AccountStatus.
- UserInformation contains LoginId, FullName, FatherName, JoinDate, DateofBirth.

I need a new list that is formed by joining the above two lists on `LoginId`. I don't need duplicate values.

I try this code but it returns multiple values, like if `LoginId = 100` then it show 100 two times.

```
var joined = (from item1 in loginList 
              join item2 in users on item1.LoginId equals item2.LoginId
              orderby item1.LoginId
              select new
              {
                  item1.Password,
                  item2.LoginId,
                  item2.FullName,
                  item2.FatherName,
                  item2.DOB,
                  item2.JoinDate
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes LoginId i.e 100,101 etc only occurs one time in each table. When i try to join these two list it populates 2-2 values for each LoginId.

Comment: Your first problem is that you have duplicates in one of your input lists. Solve this first, instead of fixing it afterwards. How do you verify that input lists are unique? Can you show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ?

Comment: If each table has LoginIDs only once, it is not possible for the join results to have duplicate values. You're probably missing something.

Comment: @BartoszKP no i have no duplicate values in list because my LoginTable and UserInformation table the Column LoginId is primary key.

Comment: @MohdTashkeel Like dotNET mentioned, you're missing something. Please try constructing a working example.

Comment: @GrantWinney 2-2 values means two same rows .

Comment: @Mohd Waseem Ya i got the Same Output

Comment: @MohdWaseem This is an incorrect edit. Ask in the comments for OP to update the question if you need something more. I don't think the problem is that people can't imagine what duplicates look like. The problem is that the scenario leading to these duplicates is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Use `joined.Distint()` method for unique values..

Answer (score 1):

```
var joined = (from item1 in loginList 
                         join item2 in users
                         on item1.LoginId equals item2.LoginId
                         orderby item1.LoginId
                          select new UserData
                          {
                              Password = item1.Password,
                              LoginId = item2.LoginId,
                              FullName = item2.FullName,
                              FatherName = item2.FatherName,
                              DOB = item2.DOB,
                              JoinDate = item2.JoinDate

                          }).Distinct(new UserDataComparer()).ToList();

public class UserData
{
    public string Password {get;set;}
    public int LoginId {get;set;}
    public string FullName {get;set;}
    public string FatherName {get;set;}
    public DateTime DOB {get;set;}
    public DateTime JoinDate {get;set;}                  
}

public class UserDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<UserData>
{
    public bool Equals(UserData x, UserData y)
    {
        return x.LoginId == y.LoginId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(UserData obj)
    {
        return obj.LoginId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Distinct() work that way? Which EqualityComparer would it use?

Comment: This is nonsense. You're fixing a problem that doesn't exist. If input lists are unique, then it's impossible for `join` to magically generate duplicates. Something else is wrong in OP's code.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't know all logic, maybe he has non uniq LoginId in Users list, maybe it possible to have many users to one login, why not?

Comment: @RomanIzosimov Of course he has. But the solution is not to use `Distinct` afterewards, but to fix the problem with input lists. This suggests that OP has a problem with their data retrieval and/or persistence. And even more - he isn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerable.Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is exactly what you looking for

See examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)